# How to add post processing to .Net Core OData?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have an OData Controller which looks pretty standard.

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GridData")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IQueryable<GridData>> GetGridData(ODataQueryOptions<GridData> odataOptions)
{
    var query = odataOptions.ApplyTo(_service.GetGridDataQueryable()) as IQueryable<GridData>
    return query;
}
```

Projection looks like this :

```
.Select(async x =>
{
   //Pretty resource heavy
   x.Ownership = await _ownershipService.ComputeAsync(_currentUser)); 
   return x;
})
.Select(t => t.Result)
.ToList();
```

Now the problem is that I need to actually return a GridDataDTO object from this call. There is some processing that cannot be done at the database level. The processing is pretty heavy so I would not like to add it inside the GetGridDataQueryable().Also the processing is async, and need a materialized result set to be able to apply it.

I also need to return the IQueryable in the controller to be able to benefit from $count, $select, etc .

This hooks up to a pretty complex grid with a lot of options for filtering/sorting so I would not like to remove the OData functionality.

Is there a simple way to add postprocessing here ? After the result is materialized, project it to my GridDataDTO ?

There is no need for insert/update/delete support, as this will be only used for read operations.

Comment: Without knowing the structures of the objects in question we cant easily offer you explicit solutions, but once you have materialized the record set , perhaps with .ToList(), you can do whatever manipulations you need before you return the set, or an entirely new one.

Comment: The problem with the .ToList() is that it won't support $count calls that way. Nothing is returned in terms of "@odata.*****". It seems that i need to let the OData processor do it's magic, and then apply a post processing to the result.

Comment: If you are post-processing, $count can not really be trusted to mean as much anymore, is that $count before or after the record set was processed? You can fake an IQueryable result from a list in memory but $count now can only apply to the modified result set and not the underlying table, which may not suit all applications

Comment: Manipulation is done in terms of projection to another DTO, changing the class. There is no change in terms of item count.

Comment: See my answer then, although no project took place, it should be obvious how an when you could put that in, next time add that detail and some more specifics to your post, like the logic for your projection to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement for your controller method to only pass through a query from the database, in fact your method does not *need* to  return an `IQueryable<T>` result at all!

> You can still benefit from OData `$select`, `$expand` and `$filter` operators on result sets that are not `IQueryable<T>`, but you lose most of the performance benefits of doing so and you have to prepare you data so that the operators can be processed, and you will have to explicitly decorate your endpoint with the `[EnableQuery]` attribute.

In the following example you current query is materialized into memory, after applying the query options, then we can iterate over the set and manipulate it as we need to.
In the end the same recordset, with the modified records is returned, cast as *queryable* to match the method signature, however the method would still function the same if the result was `IEnumerable<T>`

> There is a strong argument that says you should return `IEnumerable<T>` because it conveys the correct information that the recordset has been materialized and is not deferred.

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GridData")]
public async Task<IQueryable<GridDataDTO>> GetGridData(ODataQueryOptions<GridData> odataOptions)
{
    // NOTE: GridDataDTO : GridData
    // apply $filter, $top and $skip to the DB query
    IQueryable<GridData> query = odataOptions.ApplyTo(_service.GetGridDataQueryable());
    // materialize
    var list = query.ToList();

    // project into DTO
    List<GridDataDTO> output = list.Select(async x =>
    {
        var o = new GridDataDTO(x);
        o.Ownership = await _ownershipService.ComputeAsync(_currentUser));
    }).ToList();
    
    // return, as Queryable
    return output.AsQueryable();
}
```

## UPDATE:

When the manipulations involve projection into a new type, then to properly support OData query options the type defined in your `ODataQueryOptions<>` needs to be *assignable* from the output element type. You can do this through inheritance or with implicit cast definitions.

If an explicit cast is required (or no cast is available at all) then you will have to manually validate the `ApplyTo` logic, the `ODataQueryOptions` must be a valid type reference to match the output.

Comment: The problem that i have with this approach, is that the filtering/top/skip will be applied only after the method exits. This will lead to a really bad performance, as the manipulation will be done on all of the set from DB.

Comment: You haven't described your logic, so its hard to give you a one size fits all solution. You can apply $top, $skip, $filter before your projection, that is what the `.ApplyTo` call is doing, but if you apply first then your $filter expression needs to operate on non modified fields. It is possible to also apply different query options independently or entirely manually if you need to. You need a more specific code example if you want a more specific solution.

Comment: The other option is to apply the projections purely in linq, perhaps returning a different DTO or starting from a different data query. It can certainly be done, but the solution will be highly specific to your query, the OData options you want to support and the nature of your projections.

Comment: Thought there would be an easy way to apply this post processing (whatever it might be), after the OData pipeline finishes it's job. I don't want to rewrite the OData filtering into Linq. Something like an interceptor.

Comment: You're missing the point, in the first line the `odataOptions.ApplyTo` _IS_ applying the incoming query operators to the deferrable query. It's being as optimized as it can. What you are trying to do is generally rather simple, and yes you _can_ use an interceptor, but I've only needed to in a very small set of highly specific scenarios. Don't forget the post processing is generally it is a trade off between how much manipulation you _NEED_ done on the server, and how much of it is easier to achieve on the client.

Comment: I can't really modify my solution with the projection you have shown, it can work, but there is not enough information available to me about the schema to adequately respond. If you need filtering before your projection, then apply the filter then, if you only need `$skip` and `$top` then just apply those query options on their own. Have a look at the overloads to  `ApplyQuery()`

Comment: Tried the way you suggested. The API response, does not contain the "@odata.count" or "@odata.context" fields, which are required by a third-party client side. In my case post processing cannot be done at the db level, or at the client level. I would have loved to be able to do that, so I would not require this kind of hacks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220743/discussion-between-chris-schaller-and-ndy).